# Wrapper with overflow:auto cuts off table right border

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I use `overflow: auto` and at the same time not cut off the right border of the table when the viewport is enough to fit the table.

I want to stay auto, because if there are more than 5 columns I will need it to scroll on the right. The question is why when the width is enough, the right border gets cut off?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr {
  height: 78px;
}

thead {
  color: #92a1a6;
}

thead th {
  width: 264px;
}

thead td {
  width: 128px;
}

tbody {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody th {
  width: 264px;
}

tbody td {
  width: 128px;
}

tbody tr,
tbody th,
tbody td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll-holder {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-holder">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <td>1.25</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Title here</th>
        <td>1250</td>
        <td>1250</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be because of a discrepancy between the `thead` (which doesn't have a border) and the `tbody` (which does).

Try adding an equivalent *transparent* border to the `thead`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

tr{
  height: 78px;
}

thead{
  color: #92a1a6;
}
  
thead th{
  width: 264px;
}

thead td{
  width: 128px;
}

tbody{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
thead{
  border: 1px solid transparent; /* <--- */
}

tbody th{
  width: 264px;
}

tbody td{
  width: 128px;
}

tbody tr, tbody th, tbody td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
    
.scroll-holder{
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="scroll-holder">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <td>1.25</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Title here</th>
        <td>1250</td>
        <td>1250</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm this is super weird I would have never tested the borderless `thead`, thank you!!!

Comment: I just had the same issue, but the border I had was on the `td`, and no border on the `th` - adding a transparent border to the `th` worked perfectly.